# Notepad++ keyboard shortcut assignment always not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, plugins

I like to set a lot of keyboard shortcut (you can call me a shortcut freak) thus I have been assigning quite a lot of shortcuts in the ***shortcut mapper***. After assigning I found out that some shortcuts doesn't work and some will. It turns out that there are some shortcuts being set the same key combination - for example assigning keyboard shortcut of **Set Read-only = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** and the default **Text Direction RTL = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>**.

Of course the solution will be just change my customise Set Read-only shortcut key to **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** but there are quite a number of them and the only way I can identify them is either by checking through all **each** time I set a shortcut key or when I realise the shortcut key doesn't work. Which, both isn't a really efficient way especially in the case adding more shortcut keys when I got a new plug-ins or when I found that I can make use of it better with shortcut.

So, given that keyboard shortcut are supposedly to make work more efficient I had been searching for ways to overcome the problem stated above. The first place I look for solution is looking for a plug-ins which up until now I still haven't found one yet. For other workarounds, I tried to search around for changing the notepad++ config files and even thinking of using some batch files with the help of Nircmd but I am not that savvy in batch file commands and I feel it's too limited for this scenario.

Anyone else experience similar issues? I am pretty much clueless and it will be great if someone can shed some light. (I can't put a bounty as much as I wanted to as bounty does seems like a answer magnet)

Comment: All right then I will delete the stackoverflow question. Please remove your down vote. I am already pity enough for not having an answer and with only one reputation point =P

Comment: @wonea thanks for the edit! Even though no one responded yet but at least I learnt how to use <kbd> markdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to latest Notepad++ (v. 7.5.1 as of 2017-08-29). Its improved Shortcut Mapper now **indicates key assignment conflicts** and this way it helps prevent problems with keyboard shortcuts like the ones you describe. Very useful feature.

Comment: Very useful indeed, thanks for the tip. I just checked it and the funny thing is that I have an vanilla installation in this computer and already have several conflicts...

Comment: Great to know that! I am currently using Sublime Text 3 due to this limitation last time, for the nicer dark theme, cleaner UI and for sublime being much better at handle large file (>100MB). Not sure the other aspect of N++ have improved since but certainly happy to know the main drawback is solved =)